# MySQL multi SELECT query into form and then UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, forms, variables, post

What i am trying to accomplish is

1. Getting data from MySQL database into a table only containing rows where a user forgot to log in or out(done)
2. Change the data in the table (done)
3. Click submit and it updates all the data in the table into the MySQL database

I have made each input/value have its own name/id eg. (name0, name1, name2)

i am just not quite sure how to get all the data from the table to the MySQL database

**Heres my current code:**

```
$query = "SELECT ID, name, date, start, end, location, leavetype, comments FROM test WHERE `start`='' AND `date`<>'$today_date' OR `end`='' AND `date`<>'$today_date'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);

?>
<section>
<form>
<table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<th hidden>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Datename</font>
</th>
<th>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">ID</font>
</th>
<th>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Name</font>
</th>
<th width="80px">
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Date</font>
</th>
<th>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Start</font>
</th>
<th>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">End</font>
</th>
<th style="width:120px;">
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Location</font>
</th>
<th style="width:80px;">
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Leave-Type</font>
</th>
<th>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Comments</font>
</th>
</tr>
<?php 
$i=0;while ($i < $num) {$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"ID");
$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"name");
$f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"date");
$f4=mysql_result($result,$i,"start");
$f5=mysql_result($result,$i,"end");
$f6=mysql_result($result,$i,"location");
$f7=mysql_result($result,$i,"leavetype");
$f8=mysql_result($result,$i,"comments"); 
echo '
<tr>
<td hidden>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">';echo "$f3$f2";echo '</font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> <input type="text" name="ID'; echo $i; echo '" style="width:35px;" Value="'; echo $f1;echo '" style="width:80px" disabled></font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> <input type="text" name="name'; echo $i; echo '" style="width:120px;" Value="'; echo $f2;echo '" style="width:80px" disabled></font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> <input type="text" name="date'; echo $i; echo '" pattern="[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}$" style="width:65px;" Value="'; echo $f3;echo '" style="width:70px" disabled>    </font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> <input type="text" name="start-time'; echo $i; echo '" pattern="[0-9]{2}:[00,15,30,45]{2}$" style="width:35px;" Value="'; echo $f4;echo '" style="width:35px"></font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> <input type="text" name="end-time'; echo $i; echo '" pattern="[0-9]{2}:[00,15,30,45]{2}$" style="width:35px;" Value="'; echo $f5;echo '" style="width:35px"></font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> <select name="location'; echo $i; echo '"><option value="'; echo $f6;echo '">'; echo $f6;echo '</option></font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> <select name="leavetype'; echo $i; echo '"><option value="'; echo $f7;echo '">'; echo $f7;echo '</option></font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> <input type="text" name="rcomment'; echo $i; echo '" style="width:120px;" Value="'; echo $f8;echo '" style="width:70px"></font>
</td>
</tr>    '; 
++$i;}

if ($i=="0"){echo '<tr><td colspan="9"><p style="color: Green; font-size: 35px; font-weight:bold; text-align: center">All signed in-out correctly!</p></td></tr>';}
else if ($i > "0"){ echo '<tr><td colspan="9"><input name="Submit" type="Submit" Value="Update">';}
?>
```

How do i set the 2nd and subsequent rows values

> $users_name = $_POST['name'];      //Employee Name
>
> $users_leavetype = $_POST['leavetype'];    //Leave Type if any (eg: Annual Leave)
>
> $users_date= date('d/m/Y', strtotime($_POST['rdate']));            //Date
>
> $users_start = $_POST['start-time'];       //Start time
>
> $users_finish = $_POST['end-time'];    //Finish time
>
> $users_location = $_POST['location'];      //Location they would have been
>
> $users_comment = $_POST['rcomment'];       //Admin Comments

do i have to add every variable? or is there an easier way

note: 2nd lot of code is from another form so isn't changed for this form yet just showing the format i am using and unsure how to edit for what i need

all help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success,

I figured it out myself [=
i had to add a row to the end of the table with the end value of $i

```
<tr hidden> 
<td hidden>
<input type="text" name="ivalue" style="width:120px;" Value="'; echo $i;echo '" style="width:70px" hidden></font>
</td>
</tr>
```

Then this was in my

```
<form action="senddata.php" file>
```

i had to ++$max for some reason not sure why, maybe if i set it as "while ($i <> $max) it may have worked without it but anyway here is what i did

```
$i="0";
$max=$_POST['ivalue'];    //total number of rows

++$max;
while ($i < $max)
{
$ID0    =   "ID$i";
$name0  =   "name$i";
$date0  =   "rdate$i";
$start0 =   "start-time$i";
$end0   =   "end-time$i";
$location0 =    "location$i";
$leavetype0=    "leavetype$i";
$comment0  =    "comment$i";


$users_ID = $_POST[$ID0];
$users_name = $_POST[$name0];       
$users_date= $_POST[$date0];            
$users_start = $_POST[$start0];
$users_end = $_POST[$end0];
$users_location = $_POST[$location0];
$users_leavetype = $_POST[$leavetype0];
$users_comment = $_POST[$comment0];

$users_ID = mysql_real_escape_string($users_ID);    
$users_name = mysql_real_escape_string($users_name);
$users_date= mysql_real_escape_string($users_date);
$users_start = mysql_real_escape_string($users_start);
$users_end = mysql_real_escape_string($users_end);
$users_location = mysql_real_escape_string($users_location);
$users_leavetype = mysql_real_escape_string($users_leavetype);
$users_comment= mysql_real_escape_string($users_comment);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `mydb_mydb`.`mydb` (`datename` `ID`, `name`, `location`, `start`, `end`, `date`, `Leavetype`, `comments`) VALUES ('$users_leavetype$users_date$users_name', '$users_ID', '$users_name', '$users_location', '$users_start', '$users_end', '$users_date', '$users_leavetype', '$users_comment') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `start`='$users_start', `end`='$users_end', `Leavetype`='$users_leavetype', `comments`= '$users_comment' ");
++$i;}

mysql_close();
?>
```

note: datename is my unique column so someone cant signin/out twice in one day

Answer (score 0):

You having mistake in `mysql_num_row()`; Its

```
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

not

```
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
```

read manual [mysql_num_row()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

Comment: Hmm okay, will change that and see if it still works. Because it's currently receiving the data correctly.

Comment: at the bottom of the page you mentioned
"Note:
For backward compatibility, the following deprecated alias may be used: mysql_numrows()"